# Plugin or method to delete uploads not in media library?

Tags: plugins, uploads, media

Over time working on a local and development server I've accumulated some junk in my `wp-content/uploads folder` which are not in the database. The folder and database entry are fairly large and so I was wondering if there was a plugin or way to do some type of "garbage collection" and delete items in the uploads folder which are not in the media library.

Comment: I am looking for a plugin that could do that as well. It's very doable, the user would just have to check everything before confirming the deletion.

Comment: Might also be cool to "move" the files to another directory and then move them back as they are requested (i.e. the 404 trigger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this. You could query the WP database for wp_posts that are media uploads and then run a script to match those again the files in the uploads folder, but even this would be a little shaky.

Comment: This is also a security issue as it will not show up foreign files in uploads directory.